# Phrase to express activity in landing a job

Tags: word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-request, phrasal-verbs

In addition to [Use of "gain employment" expression?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/130805/use-of-gain-employment-expression) :

I'd like to say that former students landed jobs at great companies. At the the same time I'd like to express their efforts/actions and active attitude to it. So they were not only hired, but found those jobs and employed themselves. What are the best phrases for it:

- landed jobs
- got jobs
- gained employment
- employed themselves

Are there any extra variants?

In addition: [ngrams results](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gain%20employment%2Cemploy%20myself&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgain%20employment%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cemploy%20myself%3B%2Cc0) - is it relevant now?

To the answer: yes, they succeeded in their job finding. Some of them run their own business. So "actively networked" is good to describe the process. However, I'd also like to express the result. I fell that "employed themselves" is not the best choice. Neither "gained employment" - [*gain employment* is fine there, if you're talking about being employed in general, at some time in the future](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/130805/use-of-gain-employment-expression#comment263206_130805)

Comment: Related:  [What is the difference between "job" and "job opportunity"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48609)

Answer (score 2):

The phrase you may be looking for is

> **actively networked** to find their job

it generally means in order to find a job they contacted people whom they either already knew, or wanted to know and reached out to companies they were interested in working for.

Your phrases

> landed jobs
>   got jobs
>   gained employment

is the result of successful active networking, that is getting a job.

> employed themselves

doesn't really make sense unless they started their own company.